# Show $\text{range}A\cap\text{range}B=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be $nxn$ real matrices with $A+B=I$ and $\text{rank}A+\text{rank}B=n$. Show $\text{range}A\cap\text{range}B=\{0\}$.

I haven't been able to get very far with this problem. I know that $\text{rank}B$ must equal $\text{nullity}A$, and obviously $\{0\}\in\text{range}A\cap\text{range}B$, since they're both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm stuck on how to use $A+B=I$ to proceed with the other inclusion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of a sum formula yields $$\dim (\operatorname{im}A+\operatorname{im}B) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) - \dim (\operatorname{im} A \cap \operatorname{im}B) = n - \dim (\operatorname{im} A \cap \operatorname{im}B).$$

Now we obviously have $\operatorname{im}(A+B) \subseteq \operatorname{im}A + \operatorname{im}B$, and so $$\dim(\operatorname{im}A+\operatorname{im}B) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A+B) = \operatorname{rank}(I) = n.$$ Hence $\dim(\operatorname{im}A+\operatorname{im}B) = n$, and $\dim (\operatorname{im} A \cap \operatorname{im}B) = 0$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if $B$ or $A$ are identity we are done.

Otherwise neither are trivial.

Let $T_A, T_B$ be the linear transformations they represent.

Let $v \in ImgA \cap ImgB$, then $\exists u_A,u_B$ s.t $T_A(u_A) = v, T_B(u_B) = v$

As you said, $dimKer B = dimImgA$ and vice versa.

But in fact, letting $l \in kerT_A$, $T_A+T_B(l) = T_B(l) = l$

so $l \in ImgT_B$ then $KerB = ImgA$ and vice versa.

So, $Id(v) = T_A + T_B(v) = 0$